# Washington, D.C. Shapefile

Tags: data-request, geocoding

I am looking for a shapefile of the Capital city of the United States.
I have looked in [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/tag/world-file/) and [GeoTECHO](http://techcenter.jefferson.kctcs.edu/data/), but I have only found a list of cites that covers the entire world.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an abundance of open GIS data on Washington, D.C., however they all have distinct characteristics. Your going to have to pick through and select which one(s) fit what you need.

[Search Code for DC's Open Data Portal for Files of Type "SHP"](http://data.codefordc.org/dataset?q=&res_format=SHP&sort=score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc)
Note: There are exponentially many more datasets here in `.geojson` format; converting to `.shp` can be easily done in a number of ways, I prefer [using Q-GIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) for small/one-off/testing conversions.

[Search DC.gov's Open Data Portal for "shapefile"](http://opendata.dc.gov/datasets?q=shapefile).
DC.gov typically releases datasets in a number of GIS formats, including shapefile; searching for what you want in the portal will most likely be more fruitful.

None of these are pointing to a particular dataset, because the request is vague; there are a plethora of DC shapefiles in both portals, each having distinct characteristics from others. Census Tracts, Wards, Boundaries, City Line, Districts, Voting Districts, Neighborhoods, are just a few of the many options there are to choose from.